# Scalatra Logging Error

Tags: scala, logging, scalatra

I get the following error/warning when starting my Scalatra web app:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I have the following dependencies:

```
"org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % ScalatraVersion,
"org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalate" % ScalatraVersion,
"org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-specs2" % ScalatraVersion % "test",
"org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-json" % ScalatraVersion,
"org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-auth" % ScalatraVersion,
"org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalatest" % ScalatraVersion % "test",
"org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0" % "test",
"commons-lang" % "commons-lang" % "2.6",
"c3p0" % "c3p0" % "0.9.1.2",
"net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.11.1",
"org.json4s"   %% "json4s-native" % "3.2.6",
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.1.0-M2",
"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.2-1002-jdbc4",
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.3",
"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.8.v20121106" % "container",
"org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" %      "container;provided;test" artifacts (Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar"))
```

I just want regular logging, to see which requests that comes in etc.

EDIT: Actually this warning doesn't do anything and you can still use the logging module as usual. So now I still have this warning but I'm logging through the logging framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change logback version to `1.0.13`. E.g.

```
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.13"
```